# Adjoint linear operators and inner products question; why does $\langle T(x),T(x)\rangle =\langle T^*T(x),x\rangle $?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, adjoint-operators, orthogonality

I have seen this multiple times in my textbook; $\langle T(x),T(x)\rangle=\langle T^*T(x),x\rangle$; why is this true?

I know the definition of adjoint is if $\langle x,T(y)\rangle=\langle T^*(x),y\rangle$. But I don't see the connection.

Thanks

Comment: I think there is nothing confusing from $< x,T(y)>=< T^*(x),y>$ to $< T(x),T(x)>=< T^*T(x),x>$, regard $"T(x)"$ as $"x"$, then by the definition of adjoint.

Comment: I don't know why I was confused

Comment: @user201043 You should make that comment an answer.

Comment: And then accept it.